# Jetpack Compose - HorizontalPager item spacing/padding for items with max width

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, jetpack-compose-accompanist, android-jetpack-compose-pager

Using Jetpack Compose and the [accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) pager, I'm trying to create a [`HorizontalPager`](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager) where:

1. Edges of items to the left and right of current item are shown
2. There is a max width to the `Pager` items

As an example, I wrote the following code (for simplicities sake, I made `Text` items, but in reality, I'm actually making more complex `Card` items):

```
@Composable
fun MyText(modifier: Modifier) {
  Text(
    text = LOREM_IPSUM_TEXT,
    modifier = modifier
      .wrapContentHeight()
      .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red))
  )
}

@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun MyPager(pagerItem: @Composable () -> Unit = {}) {
  Scaffold {
    Column(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        // In case items in the VP are taller than the screen -> scrollable
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
      HorizontalPager(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(32.dp),
        itemSpacing = 16.dp,
        count = 3,
      ) {
        pagerItem()
      }
    }
  }
}

@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyPager_200dpWidth() {
  MyPager { MyText(modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = 200.dp)) }
}

@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyPager_500dpWidth() {
  MyPager { MyText(modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = 500.dp)) }
}

@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyPager_FillMaxWidth() {
  MyPager { MyText(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I make the item have a max width that seems to be smaller than the screen width (see `MyPager_200dpWidth`), I no longer see the items on the side anymore. On the other hand, using items with **larger** max widths (See `MyPager_500dpWidth`) or `fillMaxWidth` (See `MyPager_FillMaxWidth`) allows me to see the items on the side.

It seems weird to me that items with the **smaller** max width are actually taking up more horizontal space than the items with the **larger** max width. This can be shown in the Preview section...

[image: Preview Comparison]

See how the images on the left (`MyPager_500dpWidth) and middle (`MyPager_FillMaxWidth`) show the next item, while the image on the right (`MyPager_200dpWidth`) takes up the whole screen? Here's another comparison when hovering my mouse over the items to see the skeleton boxes...

[image: Preview Comparison with skeleton]

Just wondering if someone could help me figure out how I can solve this use case. Is it possible that there's a bug in Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page size is controlled by the `HorizontalPager.contentPadding` parameter.

Applying `widthIn(max = 200.dp)` to your text only reduces the size of your element inside the page, while the page size remains unchanged.

Applying more padding should solve your problem, for example, `contentPadding = PaddingValues(100.dp)` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like I'll need to do calculations based off of the screen width to determine the contentPadding

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by adding your contentPadding like this

```
val horizontalPadding = 16.dp
val itemWidth = 340.dp
val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = horizontalPadding, end = (screenWidth - itemWidth + horizontalPadding).dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this in 2024 while using the `HorizontalPager` from the `foundation-android:1.6.0-alpha08` library, there's now a `pageSize` parameter for restricting the item size:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyPager() {
    HorizontalPager(
        pageSize = PageSize.Fixed(200.dp),
        state = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {1})
    ) { ... }
```

See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager#custom-page